# Vue Apollo Query stuck in the loading state after updating with subscription

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo, graphql-subscriptions

I have a [SubscribeToMore](https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more) subscription and I want it to update my query. I see the result of my subscription, but the query isn't updated after the `return` statement and the app is tucked in the loading state. Here is my query with the subscription:

```
cartProducts: {
  query: GET_CART_PRODUCTS,
  loadingKey: "loading",
  subscribeToMore: {
    document: ON_TRANSACTION_CHANGED,
    updateQuery(previousResult: any, { subscriptionData }: any) {
      const oldTransactions = previousResult.cartProducts.items;
      const newTransaction = subscriptionData.data.onTransactionChanged;
      const concatItems = [...oldTransactions, newTransaction];
      console.log("concatItems:", concatItems);
      return {
        cartProducts: {
          items: concatItems,
          __typename: "PaginatedTransaction",
        },
        __typename: "PaginatedTransaction",
      };
    },
    variables() {
      return {
        profileId: this.profile.profileId,
      };
    },
    skip() {
      return !this.profile?.profileId;
    },
  },
},
```

`concatItems` variable has correct data, but if I remove `loadingKey` and try to log `cartProducts` after making a subscription call, it's not updated. What am I doing wrong? Thanx in advance! Let me know if you need more info about my setup to understand the case.